# SQL Server : trigger on not inserted row

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert

I have two tables. I have defined a trigger on Table A that updates Table B when a row is inserted into Table A.

I want to prevent inserting into table A and allow updating in table B if a data with certain values is sent to Table A.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: **Instead of** insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INSTEAD OF` trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test1] ( [id] [INT] NULL )
ON  [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test2] ( [id] [INT] NULL )
ON  [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TRIGGER trInsert ON dbo.Test1
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    BEGIN

        --Insert particular data to Test2
        INSERT  INTO dbo.Test2
                ( id )
                SELECT  *
                FROM    Inserted
                WHERE   id = 2

        --Insert the rest of data to Test1    
        INSERT  INTO dbo.Test1
                ( id )
                SELECT  *
                FROM    Inserted
                WHERE   id <> 2
    END
GO


INSERT  INTO dbo.Test1
        ( id )
VALUES  ( 1 ),
        ( 2 ),
        ( 3 )

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Test1
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Test2
```

Output:

```
Test1:

id
1
3

Test2:

id
2
```

Comment: but in this solution, the insert query is duplicated for test1. is there a better way?

Comment: @FariborzDehghani, you can write strored procedure for insert and check `IF CONDITION THEN INSERT INTO B ELSE INSERT INTO A` .